# Which is complexity of set difference using quick sort and binary search?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

We have two sets A, B and we want to compute set difference A - B, we will sort first elements of B with quicksort which have average complexity O(n * log n) and after we search each element from A in B with binary search which have complexity O(log n), the entire set difference algorihm described up which complexity will have ? if we consider that we use qucksort and binary search. I tried follow way to compute complexity of set difference using this algorithms: O(n * log n) + O(log n) = O(n * log n + log n) = O(log n * (n  + 1)) = O((n + 1) * log n). Is it correct ?

Comment: Are you trying to get the average complexity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, constant does not really count in O notation facing a polynomial that grows faster than a constant, so `1` will be owned by `n`, which means O((n + 1) * log n) is just O(n * log n).

Now the important issue - suppose A has `m` elements, you need to do `m` binary searches, each has complexity O(log n). So totally, the complexity should be O(n * log n) + O(m * log n) = O((n + m) * log n).

Comment: If you add the link to wikipedia or other explanation of O notation arithmetic I can happily delete my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
O (n * log n) + O (log n) = O (n * log n)
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Properties

> If a function may be bounded by a polynomial in n, then as n tends to
>   infinity, one may disregard lower-order terms of the polynomial.